# How do I set a random seed, randomly?

Tags: python, random, multiprocessing, random-seed

I am running a process which is massively parallelized that depends on randomness. The trouble is that each of the workers in the parallel process shares the same random seed as the parent process, thereby ruining my attempts to run distinct random simulations.

Thus, I have the problem of how to set a distinct random seed on each worker at inception. My current solution is to take the microseconds part off of `time.time()` and convert it to an integer before passing it to `random.seed()`. It looks like the following. Is there a better way?

```
import re
import random
import time
def set_random_seed():
    seed = int(re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', str(time.time())[-7:]))
    random.seed(seed)
```

Comment: Turns out this is the behavior of `random.seed()` when no arguments are passed and the OS doesn't haven't native support for random number generation. Nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed

If the seed is omitted [os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) will be used - if available. You can just call:

```
random.seed()
```

If you are worried about unlikely case of `os.urandom` being not available, generate unique seeds in your main process and pass one to each process you start.

Comment: Also from the docs... """If a is omitted or None, the current system time is used. If randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time (see the os.urandom() function for details on availability).""" Looks like I found my way back to the beginning...

Comment: Is it even necessary to call `random.seed()`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19166957/10077