# In what situations do we specifiy a static seed value when using the random module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, random-seed

Like the title says, I wanted to know why we would ever specify the seed value? Aside from debugging is there any other reason? As far as I know, Specifying the seed would produce the same number every time. Is there anything else that specifying a static seed does?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166784/should-i-seed-the-random-number-generator

Comment: I use it when I want my students to get the same answers.